# Does LogStash saves the log file that he index?

Tags: logging, logstash

I want to install Logstash on my machine in order to index my servers logs,
I want to know the disk size that I will need to do so.

Does  LogStash saves the log file that he index on the Logstash server itself?

Or he just pointing to the logs on the remote servers and it doesn't take a big disk volume? 
(i have 100G log files, so I want to know how much space I will need)

Comment: A typical Logstash setup uses ElasticSearch for storage, but it's difficult to predict how much space it will need -- that will vary depending on your setup. How many indexed fields are you storing? Are you stripping redundant message data? What's your ES cluster look like? Is storage compression enabled? As a rough guide, I'd assume 0.5-1.5x the size of raw logs, then test with live data samples.

Answer (score 2):

Logstash doesn't store anything itself, but routes data to various outputs.  As such, it's a CPU-intensive operation more than memory or disk.

To store the full logs, outputting to Elasticsearch is the common solution.  When you start to make a production cluster, you'll have replicas, which increase your disk space requirements.

You can also pick whether a field is to be stored or only indexed.  That can help with space.